# What is wrong with this integration logic?

Tags: integration, logarithms

Something cannot be right here but I cannot figure out what…

$ \int \frac{2}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x = 2\ln|x| + C = \ln(|x|^2) + C = \ln(x^2) + C = 2\ln x + C \\ \;\Rightarrow \; 2\ln x + C = 2\ln|x| + C \quad \text{???}$

Does this have to do with these two answers differing by a constant or am I missing something with logarithm properties? Help.

Comment: Hi Ahd. We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: $\ln x^2=2\ln x$ only if $x>0$. Otherwise, $\ln x^2=2\ln |x|$ if $x\neq 0$.

Comment: $\ln x^2 + C$ has domain $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$.  $2\ln x + C$ has domain $(0, \infty)$.  They are equal on their common domain (so what you write is an identity), but since the domains are different, they are not equal as functions.

Comment: Thx for the explanations. Also, sorry for bad formatting, it is obviously my first time using math stack exchange haha. I’ll have to remember to use proper formatting if I ask questions in the future

Comment: @Adh: I re-wrote your equations using MathJax – you can have a look at the code to get an idea of how it works.

Comment: Indeed, since $\ln(x^2) + C = 2\ln x + C$ **when $x$ is positive**, it follows that $2\ln x + C = 2\ln|x| + C$ **when $x$ is positive**. In fact, $|x| = x$ when $x$ is positive, so really this is no surprise.